# Trouble deploying Qt Applications

Tags: c++, windows, qt, deployment

I am new to Qt and I finally figured out how to use windeploy and when I did it said "libgcc_s_seh-1.dll is missing" and thus I added it from my minGW, but now It gives me the error "The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). I used windeployqt.exe with msvc2017_64 and here is an image of my release 
[image]

Furthermore, I tried downloading dependencywalker and the only errors were false negatives in the form of MS-WIN-EXT or API-MS-WIN. I truly am lost. I think the issue may be that in my lack of knowledge with Qt and MinGW, in general, I downloaded something wrong when installing Qt or MinGW ie. 32 bit and 64 bit of MinGW, but I am truly not sure whatsoever. Any help would be much appreciated in figuring this out! Thanks!